# Как отправлять get-запрос на получение json файла через фреймворк scrapy?

Tags: python, json, парсер, get, scrapy

Пытаюсь написать парсер изображений с pinterest используя фреймворк scrapy, сайт подтягивает изображения динамически, методом тыка был найдет json файл в котором хранятся ссылки на изображения, проблема состоит в том что при отправке get запроса через паука, возвращается пустой список. Что я делаю не так, и как правильно нужно отправлять get запрос на получения json файла?

```
import scrapy
import json


class PintercopySpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "pintercopy"
   # allowed_domains = ["s"]
   start_urls = ["https://ru.pinterest.com/search/pins/? 
   rs=ac&len=2&q=forest&eq=for&etslf=7427"]

headers = {
    "Accept" : "application/json, text/javascript, */*, q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language" : "ru,en;q=0.9",
    "Referer" : "https://ru.pinterest.com/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode" : "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site" : "same-origin",
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest",
}

def parse(self, response):
    url = 'https://ru.pinterest.com/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Frs%3Dac%26len%3D2%26q%3Dforest%26eq%3Dfor%26etslf%3D7427&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22article%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appliedProductFilters%22%3A%22---%22%2C%22price_max%22%3Anull%2C%22price_min%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22forest%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22auto_correction_disabled%22%3A%22%22%2C%22top_pin_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%22%22%2C%22page_size%22%3A%2225%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1706559284548'

    yield scrapy.Request(url, method='GET' , headers=self.headers)
```

[image: На фото тот самый get запрос с json файлом]

Логи с консоли:

```
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.11.0 
started (bot: scrapybot)
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 
5.1.0.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 
2.1.2, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  
7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 24.0.0 
(OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023), cryptography 42.0.1, Platform 
Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [py.warnings] WARNING: 
C:\Users\dimar\Desktop\Pinbot\venv\Lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\utils\request.py:254: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: 
'2.6' is a deprecated value for the 
'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get 
this warning if you have not defined a value for the 
'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for 
backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future 
version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 
'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on 
how to handle this deprecation.
return cls(crawler)

2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: 
twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet 
Password: f4281bc0761bb385
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-01-29 23:19:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-01-29 23:19:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ru.pinterest.com/search/pins/?rs=ac&len=2&q=forest&eq=for&etslf=7427> (referer: None)   
2024-01-29 23:19:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ru.pinterest.com/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Frs%3Dac%26len%3D2%26q%3Dforest%26eq%3Dfor%26etslf%3D7427&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22article%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appliedProductFilters%22%3A%22---%22%2C%22price_max%22%3Anull%2C%22price_min%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22forest%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22auto_correction_disabled%22%3A%22%22%2C%22top_pin_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%22%22%2C%22page_size%22%3A%2225%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1706559284548> (referer: https://ru.pinterest.com/)
2024-01-29 23:19:30 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://ru.pinterest.com/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Frs%3Dac%26len%3D2%26q%3Dforest%26eq%3Dfor%26etslf%3D7427&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22article%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appliedProductFilters%22%3A%22---%22%2C%22price_max%22%3Anull%2C%22price_min%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22forest%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22auto_correction_disabled%22%3A%22%22%2C%22top_pin_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%22%22%2C%22page_size%22%3A%2225%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1706559284548> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2024-01-29 23:19:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2024-01-29 23:19:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1492,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 79406,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.396744,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 29, 20, 19, 30, 6235, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 300122,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 29, 20, 19, 28, 609491, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-01-29 23:19:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные хранятся в `response`, а не в `request`, как пользоваться `scrapy` можно почитать вот [здесь](https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/sozdanie-parserov-s-pomoshhju-scrapy-i-python) и [здесь](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/)

А вообще, можно воспользоваться обычным `requests`

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://ru.pinterest.com/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Frs%3Dac%26len%3D2%26q%3Dforest%26eq%3Dfor%26etslf%3D7427&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22article%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appliedProductFilters%22%3A%22---%22%2C%22price_max%22%3Anull%2C%22price_min%22%3Anull%2C%22query%22%3A%22forest%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22auto_correction_disabled%22%3A%22%22%2C%22top_pin_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%22%22%2C%22page_size%22%3A%2225%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1706559284548'
response = requests.get(url).json()
pprint(response)
```

Вывод:

```json
{'client_context': {'analysis_ua': {'app_type': 5,
                                    'browser_name': 'Other',
                                    'browser_version': '',
                                    'device': 'Other',
                                    'device_type': None,
                                    'os_name': 'Other',
                                    'os_version': ''},
                    'app_type_detailed': 5,
                    'app_version': '835ac51',
                    'batch_exp': True,
                    'browser_locale': 'en-US',
                    'browser_name': 'Other',
                    'browser_type': None,
                    'browser_version': '',
                    'country': 'RU',
                    'country_from_hostname': 'RU',
                    'country_from_ip': 'RU',
...
```

> Остальная работа на тебе =)

Comment: Спасибо, ты очень сильно выручил <3